# Error while installing osm2pgrouting

Tags: c++

I follow the steps in this link https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting to install osm2pgrouting, after I install all prerequisites packages and then I execute "cmake -H. -Bbuild" and then "cd build/", but when I execute "make", I had the following error:

Scanning dependencies of target osm2pgrouting
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/Relation.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/Way.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/OSMDocument.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm2pgrouting.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm_tag.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/Node.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm_element.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/handle_pgpass.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/utilities.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/osm_nodes_config.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/table_management.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/ways_config.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/ways_vertices_pgr_config.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/pois_config.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/osm_relations_config.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/configuration_config.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/osm_ways_config.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/parser/ConfigurationParserCallback.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/parser/XMLParser.cpp.o
[ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/parser/OSMDocumentParserCallback.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/configuration/tag_value.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/configuration/configuration.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/configuration/tag_key.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable osm2pgrouting
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/OSMDocument.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const':
OSMDocument.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs]+0x1f): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm2pgrouting.cpp.o: In function `main':
osm2pgrouting.cpp:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm2pgrouting.cpp.o: In function `pqxx::connect_direct::connect_direct(std::string const&)':
osm2pgrouting.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx14connect_directC2ERKSs[_ZN4pqxx14connect_directC5ERKSs]+0x1f): undefined reference to`pqxx::connectionpolicy::connectionpolicy(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm2pgrouting.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
osm2pgrouting.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x76): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector > const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/osm_elements/osm2pgrouting.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::string>(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)':
osm2pgrouting.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE]+0x46): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function `get_option_description(boost::program_options::options_description&)':
prog_options.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
prog_options.cpp:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
prog_options.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
prog_options.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x2e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x4c): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueImcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueImcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper::parse(boost::any&, std::vector > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::typed_value::name() const':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE4nameEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::typed_value::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector > const&) const':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool*, int)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::typed_value::name() const':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueImcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueImcE4nameEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::typed_value::name() const':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`boost::program_options::typed_value::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector > const&) const':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string*, int)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o: In function`void boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > const&, unsigned long*, long)':
prog_options.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateImcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateImcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l]+0x11e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to`boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/utilities/prog_options.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function`osm2pgr::Export2DB::has_extension(std::string const&) const':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0x398): undefined reference to `pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function`osm2pgr::Export2DB::install_postGIS() const':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0x5b7): undefined reference to `pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0x650): undefined reference to`pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function `osm2pgr::Export2DB::exists(std::string const&) const':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0x8aa): undefined reference to`pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function `osm2pgr::Export2DB::createTables() const':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0xbe9): undefined reference to`pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o:Export2DB.cpp:(.text+0xd7e): more undefined references to `pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&)' follow
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function`pqxx::string_traits::null()':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx13string_traitsIlE4nullEv[_ZN4pqxx13string_traitsIlE4nullEv]+0x38): undefined reference to `pqxx::internal::throw_null_conversion(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/src/database/Export2DB.cpp.o: In function`pqxx::transaction<(pqxx::isolation_level)0, (pqxx::readwrite_policy)1>::transaction(pqxx::connection_base&)':
Export2DB.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx11transactionILNS_15isolation_levelE0ELNS_16readwrite_policyE1EEC1ERNS_15connection_baseE[_ZN4pqxx11transactionILNS_15isolation_levelE0ELNS_16readwrite_policyE1EEC1ERNS_15connection_baseE]+0x8d): undefined reference to `pqxx::dbtransaction::fullname(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
Export2DB.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx11transactionILNS_15isolation_levelE0ELNS_16readwrite_policyE1EEC1ERNS_15connection_baseE[_ZN4pqxx11transactionILNS_15isolation_levelE0ELNS_16readwrite_policyE1EEC1ERNS_15connection_baseE]+0x142): undefined reference to`pqxx::basic_transaction::basic_transaction(pqxx::connection_base&, std::string const&, pqxx::readwrite_policy)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/build.make:722: recipe for target 'osm2pgrouting' failed
make[2]: *** [osm2pgrouting] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Have no idea why this happened, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!